# Error email Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Tengo 2 problemas al enviar correo con Laravel 6

el primero esta en las siguientes lineas de codigo:

```
        $nombre     = $request->get('nombre');
        $email      = $request->get('email');
        $password   = $request->get('password');

        $template_path = 'email_template';
        Mail::send(['html'=> $template_path ], $data, function($message) {
            $message->to($email,$nombre)->subject('TU CUENTA HA SIDO CREADA');
            $message->from('buzonquejas@lcardenas.tecnm.mx','BuzonItlac');
        });
```

Mi error está en las variables $email y $nombre, el cual me dice que estan vacios. pero al hacer un dd($email); me imprime correctamente el correo electrónico pero aun así manda error y cuando sustituyo el $email por un correo espefico por ejemplo 'example@hotmail.com', 'Edgar Rodriguez', el envio de correo funciona correctamente.

El segundo problema es que cuando se sirve de entrada una firma en el correo o una imagen dentro del correo no muestra nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para la segunda duda no tengo de momento respuesta, pero para la primera parece ser debido a que no has pasado al *scope* de la [función anónima](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php), las variables que deberá utilizar por medio de `use($variable1, $variableN)`:

Entonces pasa de esto:

```
Mail::send(['html'=> $template_path ], $data, function($message) {
```

A esto otro:

```
Mail::send(['html'=> $template_path ], $data, function($message) use ($email, $nombre){
```