# Reply to. Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Felices fiestas y pronto Feliz Año.

Os comento, actualmente cuando relleno un formulario a través hago un envio de email con los datos del formulario. Para ello utilizo `Mail` de Laravel que te lo pone muy facil.

El problema viene, que en un formulario de contacto necesito poder hacer un reply a la persona que lo envia y de la forma actual no se si se puede.

Normalmente en el controlador:

```
Mail::to('info@correorecibe.es')->send(new Cont($contacto));
```

Esto va al controlador de email para este formulario:

```
class Cont extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subject = 'Página web - Formulario de contacto';

    public $contacto;

    public function __construct($contacto)
    {
        $this->contacto = $contacto;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.contacto');
    }
}
```

Y va a una plantilla HTML con los datos del formulario.

Bien buscando por internet, vi esto para poder hacer un reply, pero es algo diferente a lo que yo estoy haciendo.

En el controlador:

```
Mail::send('emails.contacto', $contacto, function($message)
        {
            $message->to('info@correorecibe.es', 'John Smith')
                ->replyTo('reply@example.com', 'Reply Guy')
                ->subject('Welcome!');
        });
```

Pero me devuelve un error:

```
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/highas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 239
```

Bien lo he solventado así:

```
Mail::send('emails.contacto', ['contacto'=>$contacto], function($message)
 {
   $message->to('info@correorecibe.es', 'John Smith')
   ->replyTo('reply@example.com', 'Reply Guy')
   ->subject('Welcome!');
 });
```

Pero ahora pruebo meterle en el reply las variables, y no las reconoce:

El controlador está así:

```
$contacto = new Contacto;
$contacto->asunto = $request->input('asunto');
$contacto->nombre = $request->input('nombre');
$contacto->telefono = $request->input('telefono');
$contacto->asunto = $request->input('asunto');
$contacto->email = $request->input('email');
$contacto->mensaje = $request->input('mensaje');
$contacto->estado = 0;

$contacto->save();

        

Mail::send('emails.contacto', ['contacto'=>$contacto], function($message)
   {
    $message->to('info@correorecibe.es', 'John Smith')
             ->replyTo($contacto->email, $contacto->nombre)
             ->subject('Welcome!');
    });
```

Pero me dice que no existe la variable `$contacto` como puedo acceder a los datos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publico yo mismo la respuesta, no se si es la más correcta pero si veo que se suele utilizar.

Añadimos el siguiente facade a nuestro controlador:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Y accedemos a los datos del siguiente modo:

`Input::get('email')`

En definitiva queda del siguiente modo:

```
Mail::send('emails.contacto', ['contacto'=>$contacto], function($message)
 {
  $message->to('info@correorecibe.es', 'John Smith')
            
  ->replyTo(Input::get('email'), Input::get('nombre'))
  ->subject('Mensaje contacto!');
 });
```

Comment: mmm no conozco muy bin de esto pero al ver el codigo supongo que podrias habar hecho esto: `replyTo($request->input('email'), $request->input('nombre'))` no?

Comment: Ya lo probe y la variable `$request` tampoco la reconoce @JuanRivera

Comment: Tienes importado `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`?

Comment: Si correcto! pero parece que `Mail` esta fuera de reconocer las variables que tengo en el controlador del envio del formulario

Comment: mmm que raro, en la documentacion lo dice asi [mail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#sending-mail) de igual forma la solucion ya esta, es bueno aprender algo nuevo cada dia

Comment: La verdad que si es raro, no se si tendré algo mal, haber si algún compañer@ arroja más información

Comment: No te reconoce la variable `$request` porque tienes una función anónima ahí, entonces `$request` queda fuera de ese scope. Tendrías que pasarla con `use` para poder usarla dentro de tu función anónima `function($message) use ($request)
 {`

Comment: Podrias publicar una respuesta con esto que comentas @porloscerrosΨ me parece muy interesante, gracias

Comment: Como referencia puedes usar [Ejemplo #3 Heredar variables de un ámbito padre](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Aquí hay una respuesta referida a `use` https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/415825/error-email-laravel-6/415827#415827

Comment: Entonces la marco como duplicada? lo otra pregunta si responde a mi pregunta también, pero mi respuesta también

Comment: Me parece bien, por eso os pido consejo. Como la marco como duplicada?

Comment: @Miguel no tienes la reputación [necesaria para cerrar por duplicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), por otra parte adelante considero prudente aportes en la otra pregunta